# How to get an SVG to have a fluid width without changing its height?

Tags: html, css, svg

I would like to accomplish two things:

1. The SVG width scales dynamically to take up 100%  of the container's width.
2. SVG's is either stretched or smushed when the container's width changes (meaning the wave drawn with the svg's path)
3. SVG's height remains fixed to 760px. Currently if you resize the container, the SVG's height is reduced which is not desired.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  height: 760px;
}

svg {
 width: 100%;
}

svg path {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <svg width="1440" height="760" viewBox="0 0 1440 760" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path
        d="M677.112 54.1657C400.36 -43.9336 110.391 13.291 0 54.1657V760H1440V54.1657C1301.02 95.0404 953.865 152.265 677.112 54.1657Z"
        fill="purple"
      />
    </svg>
  </div>
```

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened. The canonical discussion on Meta [is here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use the SVG as background of a div and you can make the height of the div fixed and adjust the `background-position` to be top

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  height: 760px;
}

.container>div {
  height: 100%;
  background: 
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="1440" height="760" viewBox="0 0 1440 760" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M677.112 54.1657C400.36 -43.9336 110.391 13.291 0 54.1657V760H1440V54.1657C1301.02 95.0404 953.865 152.265 677.112 54.1657Z"  fill="purple"/></svg>') top/100% no-repeat, 
    /*cover the bottom part with the same color*/
   linear-gradient(purple, purple) bottom/ 100% calc(100% - 20vw) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also reduce the code to keep only the container:

```css
.container {
  height: 760px;
  background: 
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="1440" height="760" viewBox="0 0 1440 760" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M677.112 54.1657C400.36 -43.9336 110.391 13.291 0 54.1657V760H1440V54.1657C1301.02 95.0404 953.865 152.265 677.112 54.1657Z"  fill="purple"/></svg>') top/100% no-repeat, 
    /*cover the bottom part with the same color*/
   linear-gradient(purple, purple) bottom/ 100% calc(100% - 20vw) no-repeat,
   green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: @AnApprentice of course it's a good way! :p ... well, I would say the only hack is the gradient at the bottom in order to fill with the same color when the SVG get smaller than the container

Comment: @AnApprentice the code can also be reduced to keep only the container, check the update

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to the svg tag. This does seem to mess with the position a bit but might be a good start.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  height: 760px;
}

svg {
 width: 100%;
}

svg path {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <svg width="1440" height="760" viewBox="0 0 1440 760" fill="none" preserveAspectRatio="none"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path
        d="M677.112 54.1657C400.36 -43.9336 110.391 13.291 0 54.1657V760H1440V54.1657C1301.02 95.0404 953.865 152.265 677.112 54.1657Z"
        fill="purple"
      />
    </svg>
  </div>
```